# Unable to perform any action on my AWS EC2 Instance which fetches data from outbound networks

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am trying to perform a git pull, apt-get update and a few other operations which will fetch data from the outbound servers but for some reason, it is failing with the following error message:

```
Err:1 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-distro-info all 0.23ubuntu1.1
  Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.106.142), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.102.108), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (3.129.149.36), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.107.13), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.158.54), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.159.198), connection timed out
Err:2 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ufw all 0.36-6ubuntu1.1
  Unable to connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:3 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 distro-info amd64 0.23ubuntu1.1
  Unable to connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgpgme11 amd64 1.13.1-7ubuntu2.1
  Unable to connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distro-info/python3-distro-info_0.23ubuntu1.1_all.deb  Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.106.142), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.102.108), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (3.129.149.36), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.107.13), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.158.54), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.15.159.198), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ufw/ufw_0.36-6ubuntu1.1_all.deb  Unable to connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distro-info/distro-info_0.23ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gpgme1.0/libgpgme11_1.13.1-7ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Security Group Details

[image]

Comment: Does the instance have public access? Can you show security group outbound rules used for this instance?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have updated the question with the security group details please check.

Comment: `ping google.com` works for you?

Comment: Correct Security Group settings are necessary but not sufficient. The EC2 instance needs a network route to the destination which means public IP plus IGW or private IP plus subnet route to NAT plus IGW. See [Connect to the internet using an internet gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.htmlhttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html).

Comment: What is ubuntu version you are using?

Comment: Check if you have deployed your EC2 in private subnet in NAT. if it is in public subnet check if it has a public ip assigned to it.

Comment: @PiyushPatil I am using 20.04

Comment: @ArpitJain ping works as expected.

Comment: @VikramS I do have a Public IP assigned to my server. I have not setup any private subnet

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/382257/apt-get-returns-not-found-when-using-amazons-aws-repositories/382452#382452?newreg=bc03454ec41540e2959f4b3427163dd7  Check this might be something related